# Synchronising IMAP mail

Tags: email-server, dovecot, imap, imapsync

This is expanding on my previous [Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/170451/mail-caching-service).

Is it possible to synchronize mail between two servers using imap?

I am using getmail and dovecot on my home server to get mail from my ISP and store it locally. However, what I want to do is keep my server and the isp server synchronised. I've heard of offlineimap and imap sync but they don't sound like what I am after (more than happy to be proven wrong).

Comment: I think offlineimap and imapsync might be what you are after...

Comment: This question is not off-topic at all. Any business or professionals could be in that configuration, I do know several professionals that are exactly in the same context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the [offlineimap web page](http://wiki.github.com/jgoerzen/offlineimap/):

> You get a current copy of your
>   messages on each computer, and changes
>   you make one place will be visible on
>   all other systems. For instance, you
>   can delete a message on your home
>   computer, and it will appear deleted
>   on your work computer as well.

That sounds like its exactly what you want (in fact, it sounds like they use your exact example!).  I use offlineimap myself, and its a very nice program; let me know how this works out for you!

Comment: I liked larch, it was really fast, imapsync worked well too